# No Matching Signature Error Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery with the following set up:

| Column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| project783/north | {"baseball": 0.34243,"hockey":0.09348, "basketball":0.0294,"golf":0.45657} |
| project783/south | {"golf": 0.0615,"basketball":0.5165, "baseball":0.15684,"hockey":0.2156} |

I am trying to extract the max sport in Column B such that I return:
max_B

| Column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| north | golf |
| south | basketball |

Column B is set up as a String according to the schema.

I first tried to make sure the data in Column B could be split up so I can select the appropiate row with the max value to the associated project. I tried the follow query:

```
SELECT 
SPLIT(Column_B, ",") as split_column_b
```

This did not work and I then received the following error: "No matching signature for function SPLIT for argument type ARRAY <STRING>".

I then tried to do

```
SELECT 
SPLIT(ARRAY_TO_STRING(Column_B,":"),",")
```

However, all that happens is that the table nests as if it were to turn Column_B into a list such as:

```
| Column_A           | Column_B              |
| ------------------ | --------------------- |
| project783/north   | {"baseball": 0.34243  |
|                    | "hockey":0.09348      |
|                    | "basketball":0.0294   |
|                    | "golf":0.45657}       |
|--------------------+-----------------------|
| project783/south   | {"golf": 0.0615       |
|                    | "basketball":0.5165   |
|                    | "hockey":0.2156}      |
```

I am not sure how to proceed. When I check the JSON query results Column_B seems to be set as an array and when I try other approaches such as JSON_EXTRACT I receive the "No matching signature" error.

Comment: If `Column_B` is *string* type, `SELECT SPLIT(Column_B, ",") as split_column_b` should work but you said it didn't.  Is `Column_B` *string* or *array<string>* ?

Comment: The schema for the table states that Column_B is a string type and is repeatable. I assume this may be incorrect and it is actually an array<string>

Comment: but the value in your example is a *json string*, not *array<string>*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Column_B` has a json string value, you can try below.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'project783/north' Column_A, '{"baseball": 0.34243,"hockey":0.09348, "basketball":0.0294,"golf":0.45657}' Column_B UNION ALL
  SELECT 'project783/south' Column_A, '{"golf": 0.0615,"basketball":0.5165, "baseball":0.15684,"hockey":0.2156}' Column_B
),
splits AS (
  SELECT SPLIT(Column_A, '/')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS Column_A,
         TRIM(kv[SAFE_OFFSET(0)], '" ') AS name,
         CAST(TRIM(kv[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]) AS FLOAT64) AS value
    FROM sample_table,
  UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(Column_B, '{}'), ",")) e,
  UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(e, ':') AS kv)])
)
SELECT Column_A, ANY_VALUE(name HAVING MAX value) Column_B 
  FROM splits 
 GROUP BY 1;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! You were correct in the assumption that Column_B was a json_string value. The above works for the two listed cases but how would I expand this query to cover a table with hundreds of rows? I assume I would need to adjust the SELECT 'project783/north' Column_A, '{"baseball": 0.34243,"hockey":0.09348, "basketball":0.0294,"golf":0.45657}' Column_B portion of the query with something else?

Comment: Simply, you can adjust *sample_table CTE* to refer to your actual table like below.
`WITH sample_table (SELECT Column_A, Column_B FROM \`your_project.your_dataset.your_table\`)` .  Try this and let me know if you still have a problem.

Comment: After trying the query above, I only returned the names from columns A and B for the first row. I thought that wrapping the query in a while loop set to the number of rows would fix this but no luck.

Comment: Are you able to show the code you've tried ? It's not clear how you wrap the query in a loop.

Comment: I did DECLARE x INT64; DECLARE I INT64 DEFAULT 1; SET x=num_of_rows then began the WHILE i<x DO (query SET i=i+1) END WHILE

Comment: I see you're using BigQuery scripting, but you don't need to loop the rows one by one in a script.  I think you can get what you want without a loop.  Would you post another question with full script you've tried so that I check that out ?

Comment: Just posted a new question!

Comment: can't find the new post.